# pymode Vim can't run libraries from anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim, anaconda

If i write this on vim

```
1 import numpy as np  
2   
3 i = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])      
4 print(i)
```

and if i input `leader,r` to execute the code on the pymode-VIM i get

```
file.py                                                       4,8            Bot
file.py|1 error| in <module> import numpy as np ImportError: No module named 'numpy
```

But it do `:!python3 file.py` on vim, i get the results i want.

I simply do not know what is happening. I want it set to the Anaconda distribuition python3 i have installed here.

on the .vimrc file i have already put a line: `let g:pymode_python = 'python3'`

I am using Ubuntu

Thanks in advance